# storing duplicates in Firestore

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i currently made a code that allows to import a CSV file into the website,transform it to JSON and then upload it to the firestore database,however in the unique ID that i want to provide for the document names,i have duplicates,because some information in the duplicates are different but i need them none the less,so when there are duplicates firestore only inserts the first document and if it's duplicated it ignores it,my question is,how can i do something that when firestore,finds duplicates,it adds them to a different collection,for example,i have an id called BMW for a collection called cars,BMW will be added to cars collection,then let's say i have 2 more instances of BMW,i want them to be added to the collection called CARS(duplicate)and i want both BMWS to be uploaded into that collection,not just 1,is this achievable? if yes how can i achieve this?,
thank you

Comment: It would be easier to preprocess the file according to your goals rather than giving it raw to firestore.

Comment: the problem is that the file is given to me,i work for a company and they give me the files,and i have to achieve their needs based on the file they hand me,and im not really allowed to alter it,that's why i need to achieve it in this way,even if it's not the most clean way.

Comment: Of course. You don't need to alter it. You just want to extract, transform, and load the data in such a way it is convenient for you. You can achieve this with any scripting language.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve what you want? To answer your question: "is this achievable? if yes how can i achieve this?". Yes, it's achievable and you can refer to what @Benjamin Rio stated on how to achieve it. If you want us to further help you with your question, you might want to include any reproducible code that you've tried.

Comment: well for now im still thinking of a way in which i can do that,because at the moment anytime i insert a document that has duplicates in the ID name,firestore ignores them and doesn't import them in the database,so for now i'm still trying to figure out a way i Could do that since im fairly new to firestore and NOSQL in general